# Phone not finding ANY wifi networks

Tags: wi-fi, nexus-6

Suddenly my phone is failing to recognise any wifi networks.

It just keeps on searching and searching but nothing appears in the list.

The only thing I have done recently was I had it in airline more on Friday (intentionally) but switched it back. 
TBH, I am not sure if the wifi worked after that or not.

The phone is a Nexus 6 with android version 7.1.1.

Obviously, I wish to avoid a factory reset if I can!
I can manage with the mobile network as I have an effectively unlimited plan but that will not help when I travel abroad.

Edit:
It seems that I can't use my phone as a hotpoint either. None of my devices recognise it.
Must have broken something when I dropped it a couple of days ago. :(

I guess factory reset is the next thing to try.

Comment: Can you try *forgetting* all WiFi networks, reboot router and see if that helps

Comment: Dial `*#*#4636#*#*`  from your dial pad and from WiFi information > WiFi API disable and enable WiFi

Comment: @beeshyams Couldnt find a "disable WIFI" but found "Disable network". Can do disable but not enable. See my edit for more "bad news".

Comment: Is there any app that an check my wifi card's condition?

Comment: There are [many](https://android.izzysoft.de/applists/category/named/network_wifi_misc#group_432) that analyse WiFi but none I am aware of to do what you are asking